# Multiple XML tag by JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using JAXB for generating XML, like this:

```
<Country>
    <City>..</City>
    <Adr>...</Adr>
</Country>
```

I have special class, which generate this XML:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Country")
private String country;

@XmlElement(name = "City")
private String city;

@XmlElement(name = "Adr")
private String adr;
```

with setters and getters, of course. But, how need I change this code, if I want to see XML like this?

```
<Country>
    <City>..</City>
    <Adr>...</Adr>
    <City>..</City>
    <Adr>...</Adr>
</Country>
```

Comment: you should have city and adr as List not as string

Comment: That, in general, is bad XML design. Things that go together (in this case City and Adr), should be wrapped in a containing tag like "Address". And lists should have a containing tag like "Addresses". I would strongly suggest that you have something more like : <Country><Addresses><Address><City /><Adr /></Address><Address><City /><Adr /></Address></Addresses></Country>